# running multiple exe through batch file

Tags: batch-file

Experts, I am trying to run a bat file using the below.

```
start /wait  "D:|Silent_installer.bat" 
start /wait 'D:def.bat"
```

It's happening like both bat files running at the same time.

But I wanted the first bat file to run completely then def.bat should start. The first bat file takes approx 60 min and inbetween second bat file starting.Ideally I wanted the first batch to complete 100% then second bat file should start.

I also used call like below but no luck

```
call "abc.bat"
call "def.bat"
```

Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: `start` will run the exes asynchronously. Remove the `start` command to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Do you want me try below like this ?/wait  "D:|Silent_installer.bat" 
/wait 'D:def.bat"

Comment: No i was suggesting exactly what @bcolin has suggested in the answer.

Comment: using the same but no luck

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `start "" /wait command` with the program in the abc.bat file itself.  One of the programs being used inside abc.bat is multi-threaded and lets the batch file end before it finishes.

Comment: i just confused ,you mean this way ..

"abc.bat" 
"def.bat"

and inside abc.bat

start "" /wait D:\Setp.exe

and inside def.bat 

D:\ISR.exe
Please suggest ?

Comment: yes, try it this way. That's because your programs called in "abc.bat" and "def.bat" are async.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply

```
"abc.bat"
"def.bat"
```

in your batch file ?

Comment: Hi,When i do that both files are starting at same time for installation.each bat file contains an exe file and first exe file execution takes about 40-50min ,and sometimes after 10-20 min secon bat file starting and executing the exe file.So i will receive an error message that already setup is running.In first bat file i have base installable and in second i have service pack installable

Comment: Are the batch files abc.bat and def.bat waiting for the exe-programs to terminate?

Comment: No,I have one exe in abc.bat while it is running the def.bat getting started and invoking the setup file inside def.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Start command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to start application

Comment: No ,i tried start /wait abc.bat start /wait def.bat ,both bat are starting and invoking both exe files with litte amount of delay.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Two points here.

- The `start` command is used for asynchronous execution, so if you " wanted the first batch to complete 100% then second bat file should start", just don't use it!
- In order to execute two Batch files from inside another one, you *must* use `call` command as you show us in your question, that is:

.

```
call "abc.bat"
call "def.bat"
```

Perhaps if you explain what "I also used call like below but no luck" means, we may help you in a better way.

PS - Did you realized that your first example

```
"D:|Silent_installer.bat"
```

contain an invalid character `|` in the name of the Batch file?